# How to print a TreeView?

Tags: c#, .net-3.5, printing, treeview

i wanna to print the data that displayed in a treeview when the user click on Print Button 
by using Print Document and print it in actual paper 
 i am using Visual Studio 2008

Comment: i was thinking if there is any chance that i may use external file to get the data that displayed in the tree view and print  this file ,, put i donknow how to do this

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try if these links are of any help:

http://bytes.com/topic/c-sharp/answers/886644-printing-treeview

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5602383/want-to-print-data-in-treeview-in-c

Answer (score 1):

Create a in memory TreeView and then copy the significant properties and transfer a root node. After do that create a in memory bitmap and draw a Treeview content by DrawToBitmap Function, draw a image on page and restore root node to original place.

```
    private void printDocument1_PrintPage(object sender, System.Drawing.Printing.PrintPageEventArgs e)
    {
        var memtree = new TreeView();
        var rn = treeView1.Nodes[0];
        treeView1.Nodes.Remove(rn);
        memtree.ImageList = treeView1.ImageList;
        memtree.BorderStyle = BorderStyle.None;
        memtree.Nodes.Add(rn);
        memtree.ClientSize = new Size(e.MarginBounds.Width, e.MarginBounds.Height);
        var bmp = new Bitmap(e.MarginBounds.Width, e.MarginBounds.Height);
        memtree.DrawToBitmap(bmp, new Rectangle(0, 0, e.MarginBounds.Width-1, e.MarginBounds.Height-1));
        e.Graphics.DrawImage(bmp, e.MarginBounds.Left, e.MarginBounds.Top, e.MarginBounds.Width -1, e.MarginBounds.Height -1);
        memtree.Nodes.Remove(rn);
        treeView1.Nodes.Add(rn);
    }
```